# .NET MVC 3 Adding attributes to SelectListItem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

So I'm trying to stylize the  tag in a dropdown. My MVC helper is set up kind of like this but the real thing pulls from the DB, so the data is not hard coded.

```
@{
    List<string> ListOfText = new List<string> { "FirstThing","SecondThing","ThirdThing"};
    List<string> ListOfValue = new List<string> { "1","2","3"};
    List<SelectListItems> ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS = new List<SelectListItem>();    

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS .Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = ListOfText[x],
            Value = ListOfValue[x],
            Selected = (selectedValue == ListOfValue[x])
        });
    }
}   
@Html.DropDown("NAME",ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS)
```

This gives me something like

```
<select id="Name" name="Name">
    <option value="1">FirstThing</option>
    <option value="2">SecondThing</option>
    <option value="3">ThirdThing</option>
</select>
```

What i need is something like this

```
<select id="Name" name="Name">
    <option value="1" class="option1">FirstThing</option>
    <option value="2" class="option2">SecondThing</option>
    <option value="3" class="option3">ThirdThing</option>
</select>
```

I've tried doing things like

```
@{
    List<string> ListOfText = new List<string> { "FirstThing","SecondThing","ThirdThing"};
    List<string> ListOfValue = new List<string> { "1","2","3"};
}
<select id="Name" name="Name">
    @ for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        <text>
        <option value="@ListOfValue[x]" @{if(selectedValue == ListOfValue[x])
            { @Html.Raw("selected='selected'") }}
            @class = '@Html.Raw("option"+x)'>
            @ListOfText[x]
        </option>
        </text>
    }   
</select>
```

But this seems to confuse the controller and it doesn't recognize that the dropdown's value above maps to

```
public ActionResult method(string Name)
```

in the controller on a post or get. Well the line

```
 @Html.DropDown("NAME",ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS)
```

in the view does allow the controller to understand the method should map to that dropdown's value.

How can i do this? Is there a way to unconfuse the controller and be able to hand write HTML without the Html.helpers?

Comment: @e-MEE could you submit an answer with Jquery showing me what your talking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor DropDownListFor: Adding Extra Attribute To SelectList Option Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171014/razor-dropdownlistfor-adding-extra-attribute-to-selectlist-option-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render directly a controller action, you can try :

> @{ Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller); }

To invoke your controller action that should be returning a string with your content.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Action(int id) 
{
   return your context in here
}
```

However I think it's cleaner to add an Ajax action returning the data for building the select and after having the results, using jquery solution for adding a class (which can be returned in the AJAX response itself)

EDIT: clarification:

Assuming you've got a collection of Item as follows:

```
class Item {
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public string CssClass { get; set; }
   public string Description{ get; set; }
}
private const string EMPTY_OPTION = "<option value=''></option>";
[HttpGet]
public string Action(int id) 
{
    // Load a collection with all your option's related data
    IQueryable data = LoadSomethingFromDbOrWherever(id);
    // Build output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("<select id='foo' name='foo'>");
    sb.AppendFormat(EMPTY_OPTION);
    foreach (Item b in data)
    {
            sb.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}' class='{1}'>{2}</option>",
                            b.Value, b.CssClass, b.Description);
    }
    sb.AppendFormat("</select>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

for ajax option:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Action(int id) 
{
   //same as above, obtain a collection
    // Load a collection with all your option's related data
    IQueryable data = LoadSomethingFromDbOrWherever(id);
    var jsonData = new
            {
                    from c in data
                    select new
                    {
                        Value= c.Value,
                        CssClass = c.CssClass,
                        Description = c.Desription
                    }).ToArray()
            };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

Call this via $.ajax and in the callback you'll have a javascript object containing all your data, then use jQuery to build up the select options.

Regards

Comment: That looks like a way of writing the second thing I tried but in the controller instead of the view which is good to know. Could you expand on that adding a class after the fact with jquery bit of your answer? I feel like that would take the thing I have and make it the thing I want.

Comment: In this example how do you pass the ID parameter? Would it be something like `@{ Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller,new{params}); }`

Comment: Is done via Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller,new{id = value});}

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can try something like this:

```
$('#Name option').each(function(){
    var i = $(this).attr('value');
    $(this).addClass('option'+i);
});
```

(I am still a newbie in jquery, but I tried this and it worked)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My previous post was linking to incorrect code.

I would suggest that you create your own HTML Helper extension method. This is how I had done it in the past, unfortunately I don't have the code to hand to show an example.

You basically need to create a method that takes your parameters and returns a htmlstring

you would end up replacing

```
@Html.DropDown("NAME",ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS)
```

with something like

```
@Html.MyDropDown("NAME",ListOFSELCETLISTITEMS)
```

where you are looping the list and creating a correctly formatted html string to return, then you can add as much extra attributes as you want

Comment: OK this sounds good. What class do I need to inherit from to make it show up as part of the HTML object? Is there an example link you could find to give me a starting point?

Comment: what about using Html.Raw() to emit a normal string ?

Comment: @Dan, this one seems to have enough information in to do what you need http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs