# Getting 30+ dropdowns values to the controller to update model- MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very large form that represents a month or more of data. Each day has 3 drop-downs the user can update and then i need to save the data in  the form. I should mention I had to make a custom dropdown ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7755290/839501)) to use a style class so it's not the standard  `Html.dropdown()`

So what I'd like to do is something like...

View:

```
    @{

        List<string> DropdownValues = new List<string>();

    }

    @using(Html.BeginForm("Method","Controller",FormMethod.Post,new{ Data = DropdownValues}))
    {
      @Html.CustomDropdown("Name1",ListOfOptions1)
      @Html.CustomDropdown("Name2",ListOfOptions2)
      @Html.CustomDropdown("Name3",ListOfOptions3)

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      @{
         //Do on submit 
         DropdownValues.add(Name1.value);
         DropdownValues.add(Name2.value);
         DropdownValues.add(Name3.value);

      }
    }
```

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access form element direct from controller code without them having to be part of the Action parameters. Maybe this is what you are looking for?...

```
//In controller post action

string name1 = Request.Form["Name1"];
string name2 = Request.Form["Name2"];
//etc...
```

You could even put it in a loop depending on what you are doing with the data...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
   string nameX = Request.Form["Name" + i];
}
```