# binding more than two peoperties i.e text and value in dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have a requirement that with text and value in dropdownlist i need one more attribute. i have added one attribute in viewbag but did not know the way to bind it with dropdownlist.
on the controller side-

```
ViewBag.IncorporationType = imrSettings.GetIMRAttributeListbyModuleId(ModuleEnum.JURISTIC_PERSON_SUBTYPE, IMRAttributesEnum.JURISTICPERSONTYPE, (int)JURISTIC.INCORPORATION).Select(a => new ExtendedSelectedList { Value = a.Id.ToString(), Text = a.Value.ToTitleCase(), Attribute1 = a.AttributeValue1 }).OrderBy(a => a.Text);
```

and on the view -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.personEntityMapping.EntitySubType2, ViewBag.IncorporationType as IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectedList>, "Select Incorporation Type", new {  @id = "IncorporationType", @class = "form-control validate-req" })
```

i am not able to get this attribute1 value in html with options in dropdownlist. can anyone can help me to bind it.

Comment: Please find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19171957/2534646) hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
   [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Test()
            {
                var viewModel = new CitySelectorViewModel();
                FillCities(viewModel);
                return View(viewModel);
            }
      private void FillCities(CitySelectorViewModel viewModel)
        {
            viewModel.CitiesList.Add(new CityViewModel { CityId = 1, CityName = "Dublin", CountryName = "Ireland" });
            viewModel.CitiesList.Add(new CityViewModel { CityId = 2, CityName = "London", CountryName = "England" });
            viewModel.CitiesList.Add(new CityViewModel { CityId = 3, CityName = "Paris", CountryName = "France" });
            viewModel.CitiesList.Add(new CityViewModel { CityId = 4, CityName = "New York", CountryName = "United States" });
            viewModel.CitiesList.Add(new CityViewModel { CityId = 5, CityName = "Rome", CountryName = "Italy" });
        }
```

And In your razor

```
<select id="cityDropdown" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.SelectedCity)">
                <option value=""></option>
                @foreach (var city in Model.CitiesList)
                {
                <option value="@city.CityId" data-country="@city.CountryName" >@city.CityName</option>
                }
            </select>
```

Comment: yes it works..thanks.. but if it is possible with strongly typed html helper drop down then it will be appreciable.

Comment: You need custom html helper as described in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19171957/2534646)