# How to get value from a SelectList after choosing in a DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When choosing a value in the DropDownListFor currently i get the values of the select of enc_manager_empid/emp_managerName.
I would also like to get the value fo the emp_email after choosing the employee name.
How can I make that possible?

Controller:

```
 private void BindEmployees()
        {
            var employees = db.employyetable
             .Select(x => new {
                 FullName = x.emp_namefirst + " " + x.emp_namelast,
                 emp_email = x.emp_email,
                 Id = x.emp_id
             })
             .ToList();

            ViewBag.requestors = new SelectList(employees, "Id", "FullName","emp_email");          
        }
```

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.enc_manager_empid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.emp_managerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.emp_manager, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.requestors, "Select", new {  onchange="AddRequestorValues()" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emp_managerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


<script>
        function AddRequestorValues() {
            var emp_managerSelectedValue = $('#emp_manager option:selected').val();
            var emp_managerSelectedtext = $('#emp_manager option:selected').text();
            $("#enc_manager_empid").val(emp_managerSelectedValue);
            $("#emp_managerName").val(emp_managerSelectedtext);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171014/razor-dropdownlistfor-adding-extra-attribute-to-selectlist-option-tag)

Comment: Currently I didn't fully understand your problem. Are you want to create extra attribute inside DropDownListFor helper option tags, retrieve `emp_email` in client-side (with jQuery) after dropdown selection changed or server-side after form submit?